# How to get a shared link of recently uploaded file when using box in Android?

Tags: java, hyperlink, share, box

How can I get a shared link of a recently uploaded file when using box in Android.

```java
mFileApi.getCreateSharedLinkRequest(fileId).setCanDownload(true)
            .setAccess(BoxSharedLink.Access.OPEN)
            .toTask().addOnCompletedListener(new BoxFutureTask.OnCompletedListener<BoxFile>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(BoxResponse<BoxFile> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                BoxFile boxFile = response.getResult();
                String downloadUrl = boxFile.getSharedLink().getDownloadURL();
                Log.e("downloadurl", "onCompleted: " + downloadUrl);
                //This return me a web link to show the Box page to download the file
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error while getting sharelink", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first create the link, it is not created automatically. See this answer how to do it: [How to create shared link in box using java sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072124/how-to-create-shared-link-in-box-using-java-sdk)